# Variable not updating in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have this piece of code in another function. I am trying to change the value of a variable `percentage` of the component, but it is not changing.

```
const uploadConfig = {
     func: function(progressEvent) {
          var percentCompleted = Math.round((progressEvent.loaded * 100) / progressEvent.total);
          this.percentage = percentCompleted;
     }
}
```

It is used to get the upload percentage:

```
Http(true).post('', formData, uploadConfig)
```

Comment: How are you calling `uploadConfig.func`? What is `this`?

Comment: Could you please upload the entire code?

Comment: if you call `uploadConfig.func(someProgressEvent)` then `this` is going to refer to uploadConfig, which apparently isn't what you want. What is `Http` in this context? That isn't a standard Javascript feature, if you are using a particular library or framework be sure to add the relevant tag.

Comment: I updated the question

Comment: this should refer to a variable outside it yes

Answer (score 0):

In the code you wrote, `this` refers to func(). If you use an arrow function instead, `this` will refer to the class outside of your function.

```
const uploadConfig = {
     func: (progressEvent) => {
          var percentCompleted = Math.round((progressEvent.loaded * 100) / progressEvent.total);
          this.percentage = percentCompleted;
     }
}
```

You can find more informations [MDN - Arrow function expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#No_separate_this).

Answer (score 0):

> You are calling only object uploadConfig and not calling function inside that Object.

```
change your code
Http(true).post('', formData, uploadConfig) 
to 
Http(true).post('', formData, uploadConfig.func())
```